# Is there a way to place a try/catch block around an import in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, try-catch

I'm currently trying to write a piece of Groovy code that I want to act differently on one machine versus another.  There are some libraries that aren't available on another machine, so my thought was that I'd do a try/catch block like so:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException

def importStuff() {
    try {import static java.lang.String.format}
} catch (MultipleCompilationErrorsException) {
    println("import failed.")
}

importStuff()
```

However, this fails with the following: `4: Unexpected input: 'import' @ line 4, column 10.`  In Python, there's syntax like:

```
try:
    import moduledoesntexist
except:
    print("module does not exist.")
```

and if run, would give the output:

`>>> module does not exist.`

Would there be a way to recreate this type of behavior in Groovy?

Comment: Import statements are a compile time thing, they aren't in the bytecode and do not get invoked at runtime.  They help the compiler disambiguate classes that are referenced in your source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to place a try/catch block around an import in Groovy?

No.

Comment: I dislike this language more and more every day :)

Comment: "I dislike this language more and more every day" - Import statements only exist at compile time.  It wouldn't make sense for them to be in a try catch block.  Groovy provides much better support for dynamically loading things than many other JVM languages, but I don't know of any JVM language that supports import statements in a try catch block, and I don't know what that would even mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage your dependencies (thus support any imports) inside Groovy scripts using a built-in dependencies management system called [Grape](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html). This way you can create a Groovy script that runs everywhere. Consider the following example:

```
@Grab('io.ratpack:ratpack-groovy:1.9.0')
@Grab('org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.30')

import static ratpack.groovy.Groovy.ratpack

ratpack {
    handlers {
        get {
            render 'Hello World from Ratpack with Groovy!!'
        }
    }
}
```

This is a Groovy script that with just a few lines of code starts [Ratpack](https://ratpack.io/) HTTP server on port 5050.

```sh
$ groovy -version
Groovy Version: 2.5.4 JVM: 1.8.0_292 Vendor: Amazon.com Inc. OS: Linux

$ groovy ratpackscript.groovy
[main] INFO ratpack.server.RatpackServer - Starting server...
[main] INFO ratpack.server.RatpackServer - Building registry...
[main] INFO ratpack.server.RatpackServer - Ratpack started (development) for http://localhost:5050
```

Both dependencies (`ratpack-groovy` and `slf4j-simple`) with their transitive dependencies are downloaded the first time you run the script (keep in mind it may take some time to download all required JAR files.)

#### Solving problems with downloading dependencies

Sometimes you may run into some problems with downloading dependencies, but it happens mostly because of the broken files in the local repository. Grape checks your local `~/.m2/repository` and `~/.groovy/grapes` folders, and if any dependency is broken in any of these directories you will see some error with the name of the dependency that cannot be downloaded. Removing the folder of that dependency in both locations solves that problem. (You don't have to remove the folder with the name of the dependency, but rather a folder with specific version of that dependency inside of that folder.)